# How to evaluate $ (0.3)^n\sum_{m=0}^n \left(\frac{0.8}{0.3}\right)^m $?

Tags: summation, geometric-series

Can someone please help me solve this sum:
$$
(0.3)^n\sum_{m=0}^n \left(\frac{0.8}{0.3}\right)^m u[n]
$$
where $u[n]$   means just that $n \ge 0$.

I keep getting $$-2(0.3^n -(0.8^(n+1))/(0.3))$$ but according to my textbook it is wrong.

I used the $$\sum_{i=m}^{n-1} a^i = \frac{a^m-a^n}{1-a}$$ forumla from which m becomes n+1.

Thanks guys

I get this: $$ 2*(0.8)^(n+1) - (3/10)^n *3/5$$, and now I try to transform $$(3/10)^n$$ to 
$$(3/5)^n *(1/2)^n$$ and after that I can't do anything with $$(1/2)^n$$

Comment: i got this here

Comment: @You got my solution?

Comment: ${ 0.3}^{n} \left( 3/5\, \left( 8/3 \right) ^{n+1}-3/5 \right) $

Comment: You got the correct answer when you found $2\cdot 0.8^{n+1}-(3/10)^n\cdot 3/5$, since $3/10=0.3$, $3/5=2\cdot 3/10=2\cdot 0.3$, so $2\cdot 0.8^{n+1}-(3/10)^n\cdot 3/5= 2\cdot 0.8^{n+1}- 2\cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get $\sum_{k=1}^n x^k = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$, so
$$\sum_{m=0}^n (\frac{8}{3})^m = \frac{1-(8/3)^{n+1}}{1-8/3}=-0.6( 1-(8/3)^{n+1})
=-2\cdot 0.3( 1-(8/3)^{n+1}), $$
hence
$$0.3^n\sum_{m=0}^n (\frac{8}{3})^m = -2 \cdot 0.3\cdot 0.3^{n}(1- (0.8/0.3)^{n+1} )$$
$$= -2 \cdot  0.3^{n+1}(1- (0.8/0.3)^{n+1} =-2(0.3^{n+1}-0.8^{n+1}).$$

Comment: Can you please use extract the minus in the first fraction so that it goes 1 - ...? And operate from there

Comment: Why do you need that? It is the same thing.

Comment: Because I am retarded.

Comment: See edited answer. Seems you lost a multiplication by 0.3 somewhere, since your answer multiplied by 0.3 is the correct one.

Comment: How do you get -2, do you transform -0.6 or 0.3^n?

Comment: The denominator is $5/3$, which moved at numerator gives $0.6= 2\cdot 0.3$.

Comment: Why don't you transform (0.3^n)?

Comment: There is no need, see edited answer.

Comment: I transofrm (3/10)^n to (3/5)^n * (1/2)^n and then I can't do anything with (1/2)^n

Comment: Please post your solutions, so people can check. Extended discussion in comments should be avoided, and it is difficult to know where is your mistake.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_0^n a^n = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}
$$
Substitute $a = \frac{0.8}{0.3} = \frac{8}{3} $ giving
$$\sum_0^n \left( \frac{8}{3} \right) ^m = \frac
{  1-\frac{8^{n+1}} {3^{n+1}}}
{1-\frac{8}{3}} = 
\frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{8^{n+1}} {3^{n+1}} -1 \right)
$$
Now multiply by $\left( \frac{3}{10} \right) ^ n$.  The powers of 3 cancel in the first term, and some powers of 2 cancel as well, and you are left with 
$$
\frac{ 2^{2n+3} }{5^{n+1}}  -
\frac{3^{n+1}} { 2^n \cdot 5^{n+1} }  $$